# Link Lists and Freeing Memory in C

Tags: c, linked-list, free

I was trying to make a simple Link List struct but for some reason when I tested freeing up the data in the LL it would give me an invalid pointer error. Can anyone explain why?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void add();

typedef struct node{
    char* data;
    struct node* next;
} node;

node** n;

int main(int argv, char** argc){

  n = (node**)malloc(sizeof(node*)*10);
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    n[i] = NULL;
  }
  add();
  free(n[0]->data);

  return 0;
}
void add(){
  char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
  temp = "Meh\0";
  n[0] = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));
  n[0]->data = temp;

}
```

Comment: You can only `free` what you have `malloc`ed. You allocate memory for a node, but try to free memory for its data -- which wasn't allocated on the heap.

Comment: Is there a way to free the data since it'll cause a memory leak?

Comment: The memory leak happens earlier: You allocate memory to `temp, then set `temp` to something else, thereby losing the handle to the allocated memory. Hence, you get a memory leak and free operates on a non-allocated chunk of memory.

Comment: I've tried doing free(n[0]); free(n); but valgrind gives me a definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 block. Which was caused by the allocation of temp in the function add().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* temp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*4);
temp = "Meh\0";
```

Your assignment to `temp` is the culprit, as that sets it to point to the static character string "Meh\0", which it not yours to `free`.  Your malloc has no effect in this case, as you immediately replace it to point to static data instead.  Use memcpy or similar if you want to copy the data into the memory allocated by `malloc`.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH THIS WAS DRIVING ME CRAZY

Comment: No problem, things tend to be much harder to spot when it's your own code :) Perhaps you know them, but here are some other tips: 1) `"Meh\0"` actually means `{'M', 'e', 'h', 0, 0}`, i.e. you have two null terminations in your string. A "Meh" already has a null termination, so you don't need to explicitly add it. 2) I find allocations of the form `type *x = malloc(sizeof *x);` less error prone than `type *x = malloc(sizeof (type));`, as you only need to change the type in one place should you want to.